How to get recent entries from Dynamo DB
We have a table in Dynamo DB, attributes to be saved are as below.

ProcessId - kept this as partition key, unique for each entry
CreatedDate(time of insertion)
Filename
other random attributes

We are using API gateway and integrating it with Dynamo DB directly.
We want to get the latest N records after filtering.
We thought of using Scan with limit of N, but this is not working as "limit" limits the scanning before filtering and gives us inconsistent result.
We have created GSI on CreatedDate for the below post request to work.
{
  "TableName": "<TABLE NAME>",
  "Limit": $input.params('pageSize'),
  "FilterExpression": "CreatedDate > :v1",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":v1": {"S": "2024-05-03T06:32:22"}
  },
  "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "TOTAL",

}

We also want to sort the result set in desc order of CreatedDate, latest first.
Do you think it is possible, if not do we need to consider DB change?

For this, I would add a single value to your items (assuming your write throughput doesn't exceed 1000WCU per second).



ProcessId
CreatedDate
Filename
GSI1PK
Random




123
2024-03-02T20:00:000Z
myfile100
1
some values


001
2024-02-01T20:00:000Z
myfile202
1
some values


928
2024-03-04T20:00:000Z
myfile412
1
some values


102
2024-04-05T20:00:000Z
myfile339
1
some values



Now you create an index on GSI1PK as partition key and CreatedDate as sort key:



GSI1PK
CreatedDate
Filename
ProcessId
Random




1
2024-02-01T20:00:000Z
myfile202
001
some values


1
2024-03-02T20:00:000Z
myfile100
123
some values


1
2024-03-04T20:00:000Z
myfile412
928
some values


1
2024-04-05T20:00:000Z
myfile339
102
some values



Notice how all of your items are now stored in ascending order of CreatedDate. Now you issue a Query and have ScanIndexForward=False which will read the latest items first (DESC).
{
  "TableName": "<TABLE NAME>",
  "IndexName": <INDEX NAME>",
  "Limit": $input.params('pageSize'),
  "KeyConditionExpression": "GSI1PK = :v1",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":v1": {"S": "1"}
  },
  "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "TOTAL",
  "ScanIndexForward": False
}

Of course it doesn't have to be an index, you could use my index schema here as your base table, but that ultimately depends on your specific data access requirements.
More info on this blog post

We also thought of similar solution , but we are unsure how to implement pagination for next N data set . Pagination is not a requirement yet but is a possibility. Any thoughts?

Pagination is not impacted by this design, your LastEvaluatedKey becomes your ExclusiveStartKey and bobs your uncle.

Note that on the topic of pagination, you generally won't know the total number of pages and you won't be able to offer a 'go to page N' feature.
